# Django Context Processor and Form variables

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have a form in my site_base.html which extends to all of my templates.

In my site_base.html, there is a dropdown form which allows a user to change his role. Based on the selected role, the templates changes.

I've thought to persist this information via a `context processor` but I'm having problems writing the right logic that will persist the form value.

So basically when a user has selected his role, I am using that `role_id` to populate my urls but I can't do because I will be getting a `null` value whenever I click on a new link thanks to my logic in the `context_processor`.

I'm kinda new to Python and Django and I'm not sure how I should go about doing this?

The good use case in the wild would be Github's account context switcher.

**form in site_base.html**

```
123             <form name="context" method="post" action="">{% csrf_token %}
124                 <div class="input_group">
125                     <select name="role" onchange="contextform();">
126                         <option value="none">Select Context</option>
127                         {% for role in request.user.get_or_create_profile.roles.all %}
128                         <option value="{{ role.id }}" {% ifequal role.id current_role.id %}selected="selected"{% endifequal %}>{{ role.name }} for {{ role.event }}</option>
129                         {% endfor %}
130                     </select>
131                 </div>
132                 {{ current_role }}
133             </form>
```

**naive context.processor.py**

```
  3 def context_switcher(request):
  4     """
  5     Get a user's role 
  6     """
  7     if 'role' in request.POST:
  8         role_id = request.POST.get('role')
  9         current_role = Role.objects.filter(id=role_id)[0]
 10     else:
 11         current_role = ''
 12     return {'current_role': current_role}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the value in the session (in a view, not the context processor) as soon as it's set for the first time.

```
request.session['role_id'] = request.POST['role']
```

Then you can get the actual Role object in your context processor each time:

```
current_role = Role.objects.get(role_id=request.session['role_id'])
```

Comment: Yes.. That's what I'm doing right now.. Except I'm thinking of using a middleware to store the state of the user in the session instead of the context processor or in a view. The reason for this is because the point of entry for the user might not be the view in which I first set the session variable.